# Copy styles from many layers

Tags: qgis, layers, style, group-layer

I am working with QGIS 3.4

Is there a way to easily copy the styles from one group of layers to another group of layers with the same names? The outcome should be that layers that share the same name, but which are in different groups, end up with the same style.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a small Python script which should do what you want. Don't worry if you're not familiar with the Python console, just open it with `ctrl+alt+P` or click the [image] button in the plugins toolbar.

Open a new editor with the notepad icon, paste in the code, **change the group names to match yours** and click the green arrow to run the code. (see buttons highlighted in image below).

[image]

```py
source_group_name = 'Your source group name' #Change to match your group
dest_group_name = 'Your destination group name' #Change to match your group

project = QgsProject().instance()
source_group = project.layerTreeRoot().findGroup(source_group_name)
dest_group = project.layerTreeRoot().findGroup(dest_group_name)
for ltl in source_group.findLayers():
    source_style = QgsMapLayerStyle()
    source_style.readFromLayer(ltl.layer())
    dest_layer = [l.layer() for l in dest_group.findLayers() if l.layer().name()==ltl.layer().name()]
    if dest_layer:
        source_style.writeToLayer(dest_layer[0])
        dest_layer.triggerRepaint()
```